# How to do google sheet filtering? How to Sort?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT0X3Lky90cnTWg6RLr-J8NotNbj9-LACD0U4S0j3yhBEm6hlZEajdaIJ_OIUBZcstRlMkZqk5Ccuaq/pubhtml?gid=845418160&single=true

**I have a google sheet like the above link it looks like this**

```
Timestamp   Exact   Username of Hacker  Video Link
6/30/2020 1:55:21   Column1DummyData    
6/30/2020 1:59:09   Column1DummyData    
6/30/2020 1:59:14   Column1DummyData    
6/30/2020 1:59:19   Column1DummyData    
6/30/2020 2:59:31   Svd 
6/30/2020 2:59:37   Svd 
6/30/2020 10:38:15  qwerty  
6/30/2020 10:44:15  test                https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UZzu4UQLcI 
6/30/2020 10:58:53  test                https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbgzrKJvDRw
6/30/2020 10:59:33  test                https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxpX_mubz2A
```

**I managed to make an output like this using the query:**

```
*=ARRAYFORMULA({
 QUERY(B3:B, "select B,count(B) where B !='' group by B label count(B)''"), IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 QUERY(B3:B, "select B,count(B) where B !='' group by B label count(B)''"), {
 QUERY(B3:C, "select B,count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B label count(B)''"), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(
 QUERY(B3:C, "select count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B pivot C"), 
 "offset 1", 0)="",,QUERY(
 QUERY(B3:C, "select count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B pivot C"), 
 "limit 0", 1)&",")),,99^99))), ",$", )}, 3, 0))})*
```

**OutPut**

```
Name               NumberOfItem    Video link

Column1DummyData         4

Svd                      2

qwerty                   1

test                     3         https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UZzu4UQLcI, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbgzrKJvDRw, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxpX_mubz2A
```

**But I need the output to be sorted in descending order based on  NumberOfItem Column**

Comment: Can't you just put another `QUERY` outside of the `ARRAYFORMULA` and use the `order by` parameter to sort it?

Comment: Actually speaking yesterday is the day the first time in my life I am using Excel. type things. so Its a lot confusing for me.

Comment: =QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({
 QUERY(B3:B, "select B,count(B) where B !='' group by B label count(B)''"), IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 QUERY(B3:B, "select B,count(B) where B !='' group by B label count(B)''"), {
 QUERY(B3:C, "select B,count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B label count(B)''"), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(
 QUERY(B3:C, "select count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B pivot C"), 
 "offset 1", 0)="",,QUERY(
 QUERY(B3:C, "select count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B pivot C"), 
 "limit 0", 1)&",")),,99^99))), ",$", )}, 3, 0))}),"order by Col2 desc",-1)

Comment: @a-burge thanks a lot man it really worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 QUERY(B2:B, "select B,count(B) where B !='' group by B label count(B)''"), IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 QUERY(B2:B, "select B,count(B) where B !='' group by B label count(B)''"), {
 QUERY(B2:C, "select B,count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B label count(B)''"),   
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(
 QUERY(B2:C, "select count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B pivot C"),
 "offset 1", 0)="",,QUERY(
 QUERY(B2:C, "select count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B pivot C"),
 "limit 0", 1)&",")),,99^99))), ",$", )}, 3, 0))}, "order by Col2 desc", 0))
```

[image]